# How to create a custom error view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a same problem with this [How to change an error displayed in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612392/how-to-change-an-error-displayed-in-codeigniter)

I tried the solution from [Jordan Arseno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/568884/jordan-arseno), because that was the most logically answer that could be, but the problem is the class that he suggested can't be loaded so it stuck with the `default error` from Codeigniter.

I want to make a `custom error view`, so I tried to change file `system/core/URI.php` directly but it can't use redirect function because :

> `autoload['helper']="url";`can't be loaded in this URI file.

Can anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Change on system/core/Input.php , try this this must work let me know if doesn't work , this works for me

```
    <?php

   class MY_Input extends CI_Input {

    /**
     * Clean Keys
     *
     * This is a helper function. To prevent malicious users
     * from trying to exploit keys we make sure that keys are
     * only named with alpha-numeric text and a few other items.
     * 
     * Extended to allow: 
     *      - '.' (dot), 
     *      - '[' (open bracket),
     *      - ']' (close bracket)
     * 
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function _clean_input_keys($str) {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/\.\[\]-]+$/i", $str)) {
            /**
             * Check for Development enviroment - Non-descriptive 
             * error so show me the string that caused the problem 
             */
            if (getenv('ENVIRONMENT') && getenv('ENVIRONMENT') == 'DEVELOPMENT')
                var_dump($str);
            exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
        }

        // Clean UTF-8 if supported
        if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE) {
            $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
        }

        return $str;
    }

}

// /?/> /* Should never close php file - if you have a space after can mess your life up */
```

Comment: I tried to make a redirect into a custom page for this error.
I think if I do this I can't use a redirect because in this file maybe I can't load url helper.

Comment: this is core file why u will load url helper u can load it in ur view's controller

Comment: I want to make a custom page for that error... But I guess I can't?

Comment: just call error_404 or make this type of separate view page

Comment: I have the custom view page for this error but I can't load it?

Comment: why what's the problem ?

Comment: I can't call a load function in MY_Input

Comment: Here's the error : `Undefined property: MY_Input::$load`

Comment: that happen when I tried to load a view for this error

Comment: Make sure that your controller extends CI_Controller and that you call the parent constructor in your own

Comment: Can that MY_Input extend into two class?

Comment: two classes cannot be of same name

Comment: Ok, so I just tried to extend CI_Input and CI_Loader to load view...
Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: from what I tried, I can't extend two class into one class, so I can't load my view