# How to change an error displayed in codeigniter for disallowed character in url?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a same problem with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612392/how-to-change-an-error-displayed-in-codeigniter)...

I tried the solution from @Jordan Arseno, because that was the most logically answer that could be, but the problem is the class that he sugested can't be loaded so it stuck with the default error from Codeigniter.

I want to make a custom error view, so I tried to change file system/core/URI.php directly but it can't use redirect function because : 
 `autoload['helper']="url";`can't be loaded in this URI file. 
Can anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: @MahdiMajidzadeh, In CI 3, do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter 3 for changing error page's style, change Views files in views/errors folder.

for changing error message, you must edit language files!